# UpdatePanel not coming up again after refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, google-visualization

I am trying to display some data on the gauge and chart using google service.

Well I am facing a bit of trouble

1. I want to display the live values on the gauge(as soon as it enters into database)
2. And gauage is not refreshing after the specified interval.

My code for asp.net file is

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="lt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </div>
            <div id='chart_div'>
            </div>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer" Interval="10000" runat="server" ontick="Timer_Tick" >
            </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

C# Content is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        // here i am taking a object of StringBuilder class named str  
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            //if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                // here i am calling function  chart_bind(); in the page load event of the page
                bind_chart();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void bind_chart()
        {
            // here i am using SqlDataAdapter for the sql server select query
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top(10) * from Test", con);
            // here am taking datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // here datatale dt is fill wit the adp
                adp.Fill(dt);
                // this string m catching in the stringbuilder class
                // in the str m writing same javascript code that is given by the google.
                // my data that will come from the sql server
                // below code is same like as google's javascript code
                str.Append(@" <script type='text/javascript'>
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');");
                // inside the below line dt.Rows.Count explain that
                // how many rows comes in dt or total rows
                str.Append("data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

                Int32 i;
                for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // i need this type of output "  data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory'); so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this student_name using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["x"].ToString() + "');");
                    // i need this type of output "   data.setValue(0, 1, 80);
                    //so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this percentage using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["y"].ToString() + ") ;");
                    //   str.Append("['" + (dt.Rows[i]["student_name"].ToString()) + "'," + dt.Rows[i]["average_marks"].ToString() + "],");
                }

                str.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                // in the below line i am setting the height and width of the Gauge using your own requrirement
                str.Append(" var options = {width: 800, height: 300, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,");
                //  str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                str.Append("yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5};");
                str.Append("chart.draw(data, options);}");
                str.Append("</script>");
                lt.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

        protected void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bind_chart();
        }
    }
}
```

Web Config File is

```
   ?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=PC-Name\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I dont know why is is not Taking time tick trigger event for post back.

and live values to display.

Comment: look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thats How I did..I tried timer in and out side the update panel. The problem remain the same..gauge goes off the screen for refreshing but it is never coming up again

Comment: I'm not familiar with the UpdatePanels - is the code in `bind_chart` being sent to the browser on every refresh of the panel?

Comment: Well I resolved the issue..the panel was running at server side which was causing the problem. But in place of only the gauge my entire page is getting refreshed. I want only the gauge portion to get updated.